# Jenkins build is stuck pending

Tags: jenkins

Ever since we upgraded to 1.614 we have a problem with a certain hierarchy of tasks. 
Two tasks are being stuck in "pending" every once in a while.

One task is descendant of the other and we indicate:"Block build when downstream project is building"

Notice that it does not say "Downstream project <> ..."

I have tried to upgrade again and we are currently on version 1.616

To solve this I cancel one of the tasks manually and the other one starts to run, but they are stuck until I notice that.

Can I prevent it from happening or at least auto cancel somehow when it happens?

Comment: Have you checked the disk space of the slave or master?

Comment: Are you using any plugins for the projects? If so, is it possible they have issues with this latest version?

Comment: Thanks @jinggoy, / was full on the machine, neglected to cehck that at first, if you wrote an answer I would accept it

Comment: No problem dude, came here to help ...

Comment: OK, it didn't help :(

Comment: Is there really no reason for pending given in the projects' Build History when this happens? Is there just "<grey ball> #nn (pending)"? It's also strange that _both_ jobs are pending at the same time. The downstream job of the two shouldn't even become pending as long as its upstream is still pending (provided that it is not triggered from somewhere else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is an [issue in Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28926) that should was solved in 1.618

Problem did not reoccur after upgrading

Answer (score 2):

Re *"Can I [...] auto cancel somehow when it happens?"*

See [Build-timeout Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin):

> *This plugin allows you to automatically abort a build if it's taking too long. Once the timeout is reached, Jenkins behaves as if an invisible hand has clicked the "abort build" button.*

Comment: This is not working either. some dead lock in the system is present, I think the build is not yet in action so build timeout is not applied.

Comment: @Zamir You're right. The Build-timeout Plugin comes into play once a job is running.